# Click through iFrame not from div

Tags: iframe, click-through

I want to click through an iframe but not from Div inside this iframe. So how can I do this?

Like in below Image. I want to capture click in Div but want to skip click through Iframe. So how is this possible?

[image: IFrame Click through and Div Click enabled]

I know that

> pointer-events:none

is applied for iFrame, But it disable all Iframe's child as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#iframe").load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#iframe').contents();
iframe.find("div").click(function(e){ //if you dont have particular ID for div
    alert("The div with id "+e.target.id+" Got clicked");
    if(e.target.id = "expected_div_id") {
        //do something
        alert("i am inside");
    }
});
});
});
```

Or Do as follow

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#iframe").load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#iframe').contents();
iframe.find("#div_id").click(function(){ //if you have particular ID for div
    var div_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert("The div with id "+div_id+" Got clicked");
    if(div_id = "expected_div_id") {
        //do something
        alert("i am doing something here");
    }
});
});
              });
```

Comment: Thanks Shridhar, But this is for a div click. What about when I click on Iframe area and then I need Click through feature in it.

Comment: If you click on iframe then also one event have to get trigger? But my above solutions will work for your questions.

Comment: But I don't want any mouse event for Iframe means when i click on Iframe, then Iframe should not care about the mouse event like in "pointer-events:none" feature.